# Read data from text file and sort into a vector

Tags: r, file, vector

I have a data file like so ...

```
Control,3
Test,3
Control,3
Control,3
Test,1
Control,3
Control,1
```

I want to load them into 2 vectors test and control.
Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)?

Comment: Ive used mydata = read.csv("c:/Users/james/Desktop/4sec_vs_2sec_Data_Rate.txt")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `read.csv()`

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "Control,3
Test,3
Control,3
Control,3
Test,1
Control,3
Control,1", header = FALSE)

> dat
       V1 V2
1 Control  3
2    Test  3
3 Control  3
4 Control  3
5    Test  1
6 Control  3
7 Control  1
```

However, you'll need `read.csv(file = "foo.csv", header = FALSE)` and replace `foo.csv` with the path to and name of your file.

Then

```
test <- with(dat, V2[V1 == "Test"])
control <- with(dat, V2[V1 == "Control"])

> test
[1] 3 1
> control
[1] 3 3 3 3 1
```

Presuming I have understood what you want?

Comment: Err, that's what `test` and `control` are; 2 vectors. To get mean or SD of them do `mean(control)`, `sd(test)` etc.